# Issue related to activity lifecycle

Tags: android, back, activity-lifecycle

In my android game there is an arcade mode which runs for 60 sec. The gamescreen consists of a gameboard, which consists of a 6x6 matrix of coloured circles drawn on a surfaceview. There is a timer and scoreboard to keep track of time and score. Timer is basically a separate thread sleeping for 60 sec and updating a handler attached to UI thread every sec. As soon as time left becomes zero the games goes to another activity where the player's current score and past scores are displayed. If the player presses back key then previous activity (gamescreen) becomes visible, however the scoreboard is not reset but the matrix is redrawn. All the coding is in `onCreate()` method or new methods created for the game. There is no code in `onPause()` or `onResume()` methods. Then why the surfaceview is recreated and redrawn ? I dont think pressing back key runs `onCreate()` method.

Comment: Move your game reset logic to `onResume`. This will be called each time your game screen becomes active.

Comment: wont this reset the game if the player gets a phone call ?

Comment: Yes I guess that would be true. How about running your reset logic after calling startActivity? That way when you come back it is in the reset state. Or, you can set a flag for onResume to check whether it should reset or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your first activity will be destroyed if you call explicitly call `finish()`.

Even if you do not, your activity can be destroyed any time after it becomes fully obscured.

So it is wrong to presume `onCreate()` will not be called.

Comment: so what happens when back key is pressed ? onCreate() method is called ?

Comment: When your activity gets fully obscured by some other activity, OS can kill her while she's in the background.
So, either onResume or onCreate (and then onResume) can be called.

Comment: first of all if `onCreate()` is being called then why the scoreboard is not reset ? secondaly, i am pressing back button as soon as second activity becomes visible so i dont think the old activity is killed by the OS so soon.

Comment: Must be something wrong with your code but you have not shown any. Are you sure you do go into your reset function 2nd time? You could just debug a bit

Comment: there is no reset function.